# Why does Firefox remove space above and below the first letter when floating :first-letter?

Tags: css, css-float, pseudo-element

I'm trying to use css3's :first-letter to create drop caps effect, but Firefox does not render it the same way as Chrome and IE10 do. Here is jsfiddle in which you can see the 2nd "P" is cut off at top and bottom in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/0256dxdb/18/

Is this a bug in Firefox? Below is my css:

```
p.test1 span,
p.test2:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-family: arial, serif;  
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    background:red;   
}
```

Comment: Filed Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1233271

Comment: I had filed a bug here too: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214552